# Processor Overheating Issues

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

My processor is an AMD 8120FX running just shy of 3.9 GHz with a stock heatsink/fan. My motherboard is an ASUS Sabertooth 990FX. My graphics card is a nVidia 560SE GTX. I have 32GB of RAM, two 1TB hard drives, a 700 watt Thermaltake PSU, and 7 fans including the one on the heatsink.

For the last week my computer has been shutting off at random times. After investigating the issue, Im pretty sure it is overheating. When it shuts off, it will come back on only for 10-15 seconds before shutting off again. If I leave it off for about a half hour it will come back on and run fine for a few minutes. After it did this a couple of times I used Hardware Monitor to check the temps when it came back on. With nothing running except background programs from startup and Hardware Monitor, it was idling at 45+C when it came up. I know this is high. It used to idle at 35C-38C. After being on for only 5-10 minutes, the temp is over 60C! I have reapplied thermal paste three times hoping that would fix the issue, but it hasn't.

[Processor overheats like crazy](https://superuser.com/questions/414999/processor-overheats-like-crazy)

I saw the question from the above link, and I am wondering if my heatsink/processor fan is dying? I know it is still running because I can see it. It's not dead yet, but maybe on its way out? Any other suggestions on what might cause this and how to fix it?

I am also wondering if there is a program that can constantly write to a file the temp of my processor? Hardware monitor will write the current data when I ask it to, but it won't constantly update it. I have an ASUS program (the name of the program escapes me at the moment) that will show me a graph of the data for as long as I let it run, but I can't find where get it to log the data to a file. I have heard of SpeedFan, but haven't tried it yet. Any other program recommendations?

Thanks in advance for everyone's help!

Comment: My main concern is if the heatsink is correctly installed? You say you've applied paste, but if the heatsink isn't installed correctly or tight enough then the heat's going nowhere...

Comment: How would I know if I've done it correctly? As far as I know there is only one way for that heatsink to fit. It won't latch if it's set on in a certain position.

Comment: You should find it quite difficult to push the spring/clips of the heatsink onto the motherboard. If you take the heatsink off you should see the paste should have spread across the surface of the CPU and heatsink base. Also make sure there is no dust between the heatsink fins.

Comment: You MAY have permanently damaged your processor...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've been doing it right then. If anything I may have applied too much thermal paste. When I go to clean the processor, the paste is always all over the top and often  there is some on the sides as well. Also, the heatsink won't clip onto the motherboard unless it is in one specific spot, turned one specific way, so I think it is being put on correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid that you may be right... I'm hoping the processor hasn't been permanently damaged, because I have a habit of running it hot when playing games or editing video. Is there any way to know if I have?

Comment: I found the answer to the second part of my question. RealTemp will log the temperature of the processor every so many seconds to a text file. This way I can check the file to see what the last logged temp was after the system shuts down. EDIT: Never mind that. From my testing it seems that RealTemp only supports Intel. Any suggestions for a program like RealTemp that supports AMD processors?

Comment: try this one: http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/
also try to place additional fans inside you system block, maybe its not cooling down because of your fans are not installed correctly (rare problem when some fans are not blowing away heat and blowing wind inside, making things harder for CPU)